# Can ROS control a robotic arms TCP along a linear trajectory, holding a constant TCP speed?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like most industrial robot controller has the ability to move linear from A to B, e.g. Fanuc command(L P[1] 800mm/sec  CNT90 ) command. Can ROS control a robotic arms TCP along a linear trajectory, holding a constant TCP speed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292824/can-ros-control-a-robotic-arms-tcp-along-a-linear-trajectory,-holding-a-constant-tcp-speed?/) by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You give us very little information / context. In addition, the question "can ROS do X" is too vague: there are many pkgs in ROS and not all of them provide the same (level of) functionality or support the same features.

As a comment on your question: yes, provided that:

- you use a driver component that either supports this directly, or,
- provides sufficient control bandwidth to implement this from joint space, and
- use a trajectory generating component that generates Cartesian trajectories

---

Edit:

> I want to build and use a robotics arm with 6-7dof and a tool attacth to it on the last link. It can be e.g. a grinding, painting or welding tool, able to process the surface of a workpiece by controling the movement of the tool between viapoints. Any sugestens that can get me on the right path?

This seems like a true [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Yes, this is possible. Not trivial though. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWCpehyKnTY) fi. The software that was used can be found at [ros-industrial-consortium/godel](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/godel).

But realise that this does *much* more than simply executing a bunch of linear motions (there are actually very few linear motions in that video): it automatically scans a scene, detects surfaces, plans process paths and executes them with obstacle avoidance.

> holding a constant TCP speed?

As to this specific requirement: that is harder, and will probably require creating a Cartesian controller or finding one.

Not much work is done like this as motion planners typically used in ROS typically plan in joint space.

If you are looking for something similar to the FANUC TP language, then that doesn't exist afaik. There have been some efforst in the past, but I don't think they lead to something in the end. See #q283428 for some more discussion.

---

Edit2:

> Thank you for the links to godel. My daily work is much like in this project. but we mostly paint parts that we 3d-scan, segment, pathplan, motionplan, and generate robot programs. I look at ROS now, and want to learn, because I expect it one day will be capable as a replacement of our old platforms

Continuous robotic processes are typically much alike. Blending is removal, painting is additive, but the basic principles are the same.

The same software is also being used for paint removal and painting itself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-05-31**:
I want to build and use a robotics arm with 6-7dof and a tool attacth to it on the last link. It can be e.g. a grinding, painting or welding tool, able to process the surface of a workpiece by controling the movement of the tool between viapoints. Any sugestens that can get me on the right path?

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-06-01**:
Thank you for the links to godel. My daily work is much like in this project. but we mostly paint parts that we 3d-scan, segment, pathplan, motionplan, and generate robot programs. I look at ROS now, and want to learn, because I expect it one day will be capable as a replacement of our old platforms

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-06-01**:
Again thank you for showing me godel. I want to look in to that project.

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-06-01**:
I just fell over the pkgs. [descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes) do you know if it is still the plan to integrate it into MoveIt?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-01**:
`descartes` is used / was used in `godel`.

re: moveit & descartes: see the [recap](https://discourse.ros.org/t/moveit-maintainer-meeting-recap-may-29th-2018/4934) of the latest MoveIt maintainer meeting.

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-06-01**:
Thank you. The recap has focus on cartesian trajectorie messages to MoveIt. Now I am even more motivated to get started with ROS. What I need is coming soon :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-01**:
Generating Cartesian trajectories is already possible, there are just some extensions to MoveIt that could make this easier. You don't need to wait necessarily.

**Comment by [bumbastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/35591/bumbastic/) on 2018-06-01**:
Yes, i can see that. And i wont wait. But it will take me time to get to know ROS, i can only work with ROS in my free time. now i know somebody is working on making it easy to motionplan combined joint and cartesian trajectories. That tells me that I could bring ROS to my real job when I am ready.